# Creating AWS Security Groups in a Terraform Nested Loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, terraform

Using Terraform version 12, I am attempting to create some AWS security group rules.
I need to create x number of rules which may have different from and to ports.
These rules need to be create for each security group returned from the sg_groups data lookup.
So I have a nested list/map.
I think this is doable using Terraform's for_each and for loop function but I struggling to get my head around how to make this work.
Can anybody help me getting looping syntax correct.
Note: The format of the sg_rules map is not set in stone and can be formatted in any way that works best.

```
variable "sg_rules" = {
    type = map
    default = {
        80 = {
            protocol                  = "tcp"
            from_port                 = 80
            to_port                   = 80
        },
        443 = {
            protocol                  = "tcp"
            from_port                 = 443
            to_port                   = 443
        },
        service_ports = {
            protocol                  = "tcp"
            from_port                 = 60000
            to_port                   = 60500
        }
    }
}

data "aws_security_groups" "sg_groups" {
  filter {
    name   = "group-name"
    values = var.sg_names
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does your security group resource look like?

Comment: In typical fashion as soon as I ask for help I end up figuring it out myself, or at least one way of doing it.
Here is what I came up with, if anyone has any better ideas please feel free to say.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in which I have created the list of AWS Security Groups using nested for_each.
One for_each for creating a list of AWS Security Groups and another for creating dynamic Ingress and Egress Rules.

main.tf

```
resource "aws_security_group" "security-groups" {
  # Dynamic number of Security Groups 
  for_each = var.security_group_configurations.security_groups
  name        = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  # Dynamic number of Ingress Rules
  dynamic ingress {
    for_each = var.security_group_configurations.security_groups[each.key].ingress_rules
    content {
      description      = ingress.value.description
      from_port        = ingress.value.from_port
      to_port          = ingress.value.to_port
      protocol         = ingress.value.protocol
      cidr_blocks      = lookup(ingress.value, "cidr_blocks", [])
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = lookup(ingress.value, "ipv6_cidr_blocks", [])
      security_group_id = lookup(ingress.value, "security_group_id", "")
    }
    
  }

  # Dynamic number of Egress Rules
  dynamic egress {
    for_each = var.security_group_configurations.security_groups[each.key].egress_rules
    content {
      description      = egress.value.description  #Here the 'egress' is the dynamic egress block
      from_port        = egress.value.from_port
      to_port          = egress.value.to_port
      protocol         = egress.value.protocol
      cidr_blocks      = lookup(ingress.value, "cidr_blocks", [])
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = lookup(ingress.value, "ipv6_cidr_blocks", [])
      security_group_id = lookup(ingress.value, "security_group_id", "")
    }
  }

  tags = each.value.tags
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "security_group_configurations" {
    description = "All Security_Groups related configuration"
}

variable "vpc_id" {
    description = "Vpc Id for security_groups"
}
```

example.tfvars

```
vpc_id = "vpc-0be6071d37dsd985b"


    
security_group_configurations = {
    security_groups = {
#--------------------->>  Security Group 0  <-------------------------------------------
        "0" = { 
            name        = "security_group_0"
            description = "security_group_0"
            # Ingress Rules
            ingress_rules = {
                # Ingress Rule 0
                0 = {
                    description      = "TLS from Public Internet"
                    from_port        = 443
                    to_port          = 443
                    protocol         = "tcp"
                    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
                    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
                },
                # Ingress Rule 1
                1 = {
                    description      = "SSH from Public Internet"
                    from_port        = 22
                    to_port          = 22
                    protocol         = "tcp"
                    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
                    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
                },
            }
            # Egress Rules
            egress_rules =  {
                # Egress Rule 0
                0 = {
                    description      = "Allow all traffic to outside"
                    from_port        = 0
                    to_port          = 0
                    protocol         = "-1"
                    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
                    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
                },
                # Egress Rule 1
                ##############
            }
            # Tags for Security Group 0
            tags = {
                Name = "security_group_0"
            } 
        },
#--------------------->>  Security Group 1  <-------------------------------------------
        "1" = { 
            name        = "security_group_1"
            description = "security_group_1"
            # Ingress Rules
            ingress_rules = {
                # Ingress Rule 0
                0 = {
                    description      = "TLS from Public Internet"
                    from_port        = 443
                    to_port          = 443
                    protocol         = "tcp"
                    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
                    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
                },
                # Ingress Rule 1
                1 = {
                    description      = "SSH from Public Internet"
                    from_port        = 22
                    to_port          = 22
                    protocol         = "tcp"
                    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
                    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
                },
            }
            # Egress Rules
            egress_rules =  {
                # Egress Rule 0
                0 = {
                    description      = "Allow all traffic to outside"
                    from_port        = 0
                    to_port          = 0
                    protocol         = "-1"
                    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
                    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
                },
                # Egress Rule 1
                ####
                ####
            }
            # Tags for Security Group 1
            tags = {
                Name = "security_group_1"
            }
        }
#--------------------->>  Security Group 2  <-------------------------------------------
#######
#######
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In typical fashion as soon as I ask for help I end up figuring it out myself, or at least one way of doing it. Here is what I came up with, if anyone has any better ideas please feel free to say

```
variable "sg_rules" = {
    type = map
    default = [
       {
            protocol                  = "tcp"
            from_port                 = 80
            to_port                   = 80
        },
        {
            protocol                  = "tcp"
            from_port                 = 443
            to_port                   = 443
        },
        {
            protocol                  = "tcp"
            from_port                 = 60000
            to_port                   = 60500
        }
    }
}

locals {
  gw_to_mx_rules = [
    for pair in setproduct(data.aws_security_groups.sg_groups.ids, var.sg_rules) : {
      sg          = pair[0]
      type        = pair[1].type
      protocol    = pair[1].protocol
      from_port   = pair[1].from_port
      to_port     = pair[1].to_port
    }
  ]
}

data "aws_security_groups" "sg_groups" {
  filter {
    name   = "group-name"
    values = var.sg_names
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "gw_to_mx" {
  for_each = { for rule in local.gw_to_mx_rules : "${rule.type}.${rule.from_port}.${rule.to_port}.${rule.protocol}.${rule.sg}" => rule }
  description                = "MX Communication"
  type                       = each.value.type
  from_port                  = each.value.from_port
  to_port                    = each.value.to_port
  protocol                   = each.value.protocol
  source_security_group_id   = each.value.sg
  security_group_id          = aws_security_group.waf_instance_sg.id
}
```